# Optimize query selecting based on several date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

It seems like there should be a way to make this more efficient.  The difficulty is the arbitrary date ranges and number of said ranges.

In this query I am attempting to retrieve rows from the tasks table where the date (regardless of time) is 2013-01-01, 2013-01-03, 2013-01-09 or 2013-02-01

```
tasks

|id        | int      |
|begin_date| datetime |

SELECT * FROM tasks
WHERE (tasks.begin_date >= '2013-01-01' AND tasks.begin_date < '2013-01-01')
 OR (tasks.begin_date >= '2013-01-03' AND tasks.begin_date < '2013-01-04')
 OR (tasks.begin_date >= '2013-01-09' AND tasks.begin_date < '2013-01-10')
 OR (tasks.begin_date >= '2013-02-01' AND tasks.begin_date < '2013-02-02')
```

Is there a "proper" way to do this?  or a significantly more efficient way?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: both answers below (one portion seems copied from the other!) have replicated your error of using '2013-01-01' instead of '2013-01-02'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
 select * from tasks 
 where Convert(varchar,begin_date,103) in
 ('01/01/2013','04/01/2013','10/01/2013','02/02/2013')
```

or you can try this also.

```
 select * from tasks 
 where (Convert(varchar,begin_date,103) ='01/01/2013' 
 OR Convert(varchar,begin_date,103) = '04/01/2013' 
 OR Convert(varchar,begin_date,103) = '10/01/2013'
 OR Convert(varchar,begin_date,103) = '02/02/2013')
```

OR third way

```
 SELECT * FROM tasks
 WHERE (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-01')
 OR (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2013-01-04')
 OR (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-01-09' AND '2013-01-10')
 OR (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-02-02')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one.

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
WHERE YEAR(tasks.begin_date) = 2013
and
(
   (MONTH(tasks.begin_date) = 1 and DAY(tasks.begin_date) = 1) -- 2013-01-01
   or
   (MONTH(tasks.begin_date) = 1 and DAY(tasks.begin_date) = 3) -- 2013-01-03
   or
   (MONTH(tasks.begin_date) = 1 and DAY(tasks.begin_date) = 9) -- 2013-01-09
   or
   (MONTH(tasks.begin_date) = 2 and DAY(tasks.begin_date) = 1) -- 2013-02-01
)
```

You can also experiment with something like

```
Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, tasks.begin_date)) = 
Convert(DateTime, ‘01/01/2013’)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
WHERE (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-01')
OR (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2013-01-04')
OR (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-01-09' AND '2013-01-10')
OR (tasks.begin_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-02-02')
```

Comment: Between is inclusive, so wouldn't this capture any task from any time on '2013-02-01' and any tasks from '2013-02-02 00:00:00'?